# Separate duplicate riders in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook for 4D barrel racing jackpots which I designed. Everything is perfect in it, except I want to be able to make sure duplicate riders are separated by at least 10 rows. Is this possible? If so, how?

I know how to find and get rid of duplicates. That's not the problem. I just want to separate them from each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question cuts a wide path of ambiguity. Can you add some context to your posting? Like a screenshot of your current setup, one of your expected results, maybe even the code you have so far? Adding an offset to a script writing to a sheet is not crazy but without seeing how you are doing it you will not get much help from the community. Hope this guides you in the future. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example based on elements reallocation into hold queues. It takes input data from column A, process it, and outputs result into column B.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Separate()

    Dim nSeparate As Long
    Dim cqHolds As Object
    Dim qInput As Object
    Dim qResult As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nLength As Long
    Dim Content As Variant
    Dim sqName As Variant
    Dim sqTarget As Variant

    ' Set number of rows to separate
    nSeparate = 4

    ' Init objects
    Set cqHolds = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set qInput = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
    Set qResult = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

    ' Push data from the worksheet column A into input queue
    i = 1
    Do
        Content = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Content = "" Then Exit Do
        qInput.Enqueue Content
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Reallocate input queue elements into hold queues
    Do While qInput.Count > 0
        ' Pull one element from input queue
        Content = qInput.Dequeue
        ' Create hold queue for the element if not exists
        If Not cqHolds.Exists(Content) Then Set cqHolds(Content) = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
        ' Push element into hold queue
        cqHolds(Content).Enqueue Content
        ' Push nSeparate empty trailing places into hold queue
        For i = 1 To nSeparate
            cqHolds(Content).Enqueue ""
        Next
    Loop

    ' Retrieve elements from hold queues into result queue
    Do
        ' Search longest hold queue with non-empty element on exit
        nLength = 0
        For Each sqName In cqHolds
            If cqHolds(sqName).Peek <> "" And cqHolds(sqName).Count > nLength Then
                nLength = cqHolds(sqName).Count
                sqTarget = sqName
            End If
        Next
        ' Target queue not found
        If nLength = 0 Then Exit Do
        ' Pull one empty place from each hold queue
        For Each sqName In cqHolds
            If cqHolds(sqName).Peek = "" Then cqHolds(sqName).Dequeue
            If cqHolds(sqName).Count = 0 Then cqHolds.Remove sqName
        Next
        ' Pull element from target queue and push into result queue
        qResult.Enqueue cqHolds(sqTarget).Dequeue
        If cqHolds(sqTarget).Count = 0 Then cqHolds.Remove sqTarget
    Loop

    ' Force push remaining in hold queues elements into result queue
    nLength = qResult.Count
    Do While cqHolds.Count > 0
        For Each sqName In cqHolds
            Content = cqHolds(sqName).Dequeue
            If Content <> "" Then qResult.Enqueue Content
            If cqHolds(sqName).Count = 0 Then cqHolds.Remove sqName
        Next
    Loop
    If qResult.Count > nLength Then MsgBox "Can't arrange " & (qResult.Count - nLength) & " last elements"

    ' Pull data from result queue into the worksheet column B
    i = 1
    Do While qResult.Count > 0
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = qResult.Dequeue
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Here is the sample for the code testing, number of rows to separate set to 4:

[image: sample]

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted! Just one more little thing.... is there a way to get them to separate greater than or equal to a certain amount of rows. For example, I changed the code to separate dupes by 10 rows, but they are separating uniformly, whereas I want to to separate randomly, but still be AT LEAST 10 rows apart.

Comment: @LexiTaylorCreech should initial order be reflected somehow in result or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I enter them in the order they sign up, the use the =rand() function and sort in ascending order to have a "randomized draw". From there, I want the "randomized draw" to separate the duplicates by AT LEAST ten rows. When I do this, though, the output in column B puts the duplicates at the top, grouped together, and then fills in with the randomized entries from column A. I don't want the duplicates to be grouped together at the top of the column. That's the only issue I am having now.

Comment: In oversimplified terms, I need to take a column and randomize it, with duplicates separated at least 10 spots.